# Listview c# passando valor para o proximo form

Tags: c#, windows, listview

Montei um `form` em `c#` e esse form é responsável por mostrar todos os dados da minha tabela no `Bd` e colocar esses dados em uma `listview`, podendo assim, selecionar um item da `listview` e montei um outro `form` onde ele vai receber o `ID` do campo que foi selecionado na `listview`.

Foi ai que começou a complicar como eu posso passar esse valor para o meu outro `form`, pois ele n reconhece o comando `Listview.selectedvalue`, para eu armazenar o `id` da linha selecionada e passar como parâmetro de busca no outro form

Comment: É um `listview` ou `datagridview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via `construtor` da `classe` que recebe o **ID** do `ListView`. No código abaixo no `evento` `ListView1_MouseDoubleClick` seria um exemplo claro de envio do **ID** via `construtor`.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Columns.Add("Codigo", "Código");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Nome", "Nome");

            ListViewItem item0001 = listView1.Items.Add("0001");
            item0001.SubItems.Add("Teste 1");

            ListViewItem item0002 = listView1.Items.Add("0002");
            item0002.SubItems.Add("Teste 2");

            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

            listView1.MouseDoubleClick += ListView1_MouseDoubleClick;

        }

        private void ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listView = ((ListView)sender);
            if (listView != null)
            {
                if (e.X >= 0 && e.Y >= 0)
                {
                    ListViewItem listViewItem = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
                    if (listViewItem != null)
                    {
                        int id;
                        if (int.TryParse(listViewItem.Text, out id))
                        {
                            Form2 frm = new Form2(id);
                            frm.ShowDialog();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

No `form2` crie um `paramento` no `construtor` que vai receber o valor enviado do `form1`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private int _id;
        public Form2(int Id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _id = Id;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //code
            //_id enviado do form1
            label1.Text = $"{_id}";
        }
    }
}
```

com o `_id` tem a opção de carregar dados, manipular, etc.

Comment: certo... eu só não entendi o que você está chamando de e.X e.Y de onde são esses valores ??

Pois pelo que entendi, voce fala pra pegar esses valores como parâmetros, e só depois disso manda para o outro form o id.

Comment: o `X` e `Y` são do paramento `MouseEventArgs e` vai indicar a posição no momento do `click`. Esses valores indicam qual linha está selecionado e com a linha selecionada, pego o código que eu simulei na primeira coluna e mando para o `form2` via **construtor**